# Blank cell in excel not giving Cell = Null

Tags: java, excel

I want to get rid of blank rows from my Excel spreadsheet with Java, but when I try to get

```
cell = lastRow.getCell(c,Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
```

for a blank cell, it’s not giving me cell as null. This is my code:

```
 boolean stop = false;
 boolean nonBlankRowFound;
 int c;
 HSSFRow lastRow = null;
 HSSFCell cell1 = null;

 while (stop == false) {
     nonBlankRowFound = false;
     lastRow = sheet.getRow(sheet.getLastRowNum());
     for (c = lastRow.getFirstCellNum(); c <= lastRow.getLastCellNum(); c++) {
         cell1 = lastRow.getCell(c);
         if (cell1 != null && lastRow.getCell(c).getCellType() != HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
             nonBlankRowFound = true;
         }
     }
     if (nonBlankRowFound == true) {
         stop = true;
     } else {
         sheet.removeRow(lastRow);
     }
 }
```

In the last row, the cell is empty in excelspreadsheet but cell1 is not null. Could some one please help in that?

Comment: A side-note: you really don't need to write `stop == false` or `nonBlankRowFound == true`. Instead, just use `!stop` and `nonBlankRowFound`.

Comment: Your code sets `nonBlankRowFound = true` if at least one cell in `lastRow` is not null and not empty. Only if all cells in `lastRow` are empty then `nonBlankRowFound = false`. Are you sure that all cells in `lastRow` are empty?

Comment: Yes ,all cells in last row are emtpy

Comment: Thanks all for reply , I have updated code with below code.                                     cell1 = lastRow.getCell(c,Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
                   
                   if (evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell1)!= null && lastRow.getCell(c).getCellType() != HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
    
                    cell1.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    if(!("".equals(cell1.getStringCellValue().trim()))){
                     nonBlankRowFound = true;
                    }
                   }
Now working as expected.